# Help me with this code from GeoExt and OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, wms, geoext, boundless-suite

I haven't gone entirely through GeoExt. But I am trying to understand the below code, but I am struck. The below code is about creating popups of feature information. But the layers added are WMS Layers, How can a WMS layer contain feature information. It is not a vector layer.

```
     <script>
        OpenLayers.ImgPath = "../../resources/openlayers/img/";
         
        // the `panel` and `popup` variables are declared here for easy debugging
        var panel, popup;
         
        Ext.onReady(function() {
             
            // queryable WMS layer
            var zoning = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
                "Medford Zoning",
                "/geoserver/wms",
                {layers: "medford:zoning", format: "image/gif", transparent: "true"}
            );
         
            panel = new GeoExt.MapPanel({
                title: "MapPanel",
                renderTo: "map-id",
                height: 300,
                width: "100%",
                layers: [
                    new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
                        "Global Imagery",
                        "http://maps.opengeo.org/geowebcache/service/wms",
                        {layers: "openstreetmap", format: "image/png"}
                    ),
                    zoning
                ],
                center: [-122.87, 42.34],
                zoom: 13
            });
             
            // create a control to get feature info from queryable layers
            var control = new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo({
                url: "/geoserver/wms"
            });
            panel.map.addControl(control);
            control.activate();
             
            // register a listener for the getfeatureinfo event on the control
            control.events.on({
                getfeatureinfo: function(event) {
                    // close existing popup
                    if (popup) {
                        popup.destroy();
                    }
                    popup = new GeoExt.Popup({
                        title: "Popup",
                        map: panel.map,
                        lonlat: panel.map.getLonLatFromPixel(event.xy),
                        width: 250,
                        autoScroll: true,
                        collapsible: true,
                        bodyStyle: {padding: 5},
                        html: event.text
                    });
                    popup.show();
                }
            });
         
        });

    </script>
```

The map is like this :

[image]

### UPDATE

I changed the zoning layer to some other WMS layer in GeoServer. Now I can load the layer and everything else except that when I click, popup button opens but feature information is not coming.

I found in GeoServer documentation that there is GetFeature request availability for WMS layers. But there are some settings to be changed and I couldn't understand those. Please help changing those settings so that popup can show the feature information of the layer i.e., GetFeature request is accessible.

### UPDATE

This is that GeoServer manual link where I read about WMS settings:
http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/webadmin/data/layers.html

### UPDATE

Found it! We should use proxy settings for features unlike normal layers. So I should replace the URL with protocol and formats.

Comment: Jeevan, you encouraged to answer your own question, do some research, make a nice text and post it. I'm sure you would get a bunch of up votes.